# Avoid one test out of multiple test files in firefox protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have multiple tests in my tests folder where the naming conventions for all the tests ends with spec.js. I am running all the tests from the Config file with */spec.js option.

I want to skip running one test in FF as it is not supported in that browser. This is what I am attempting to do but it is not skipping that tests. Please advise.

```
multiCapabilities: [{
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions' : {
    args: ['--window-size=900,900']
    // }
  },
},

{
  'browserName': 'firefox',
  'chromeOptions' : {
    args: ['--window-size=900,900']
    // }
  },
}],

specs: [
  '../tests/*.spec.js'
],
```

I have the following in my onPrepare function:

```
browser.getCapabilities().then(function (cap) {
    browser.browserName = cap.caps_.browserName;
});
```

In one of the test file where I am looking to skip running this test in FF, I am doing this

```
if(browser.browserName=='firefox') { 
console.log("firefox cannot run *** tests")

} else { 

blah... rest of the tests which I want to execute for Chrome and IE I have put it in this block}
```

But still the test which I wanted to skip running in FF still runs.

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to update your firefox `multicapabilities` to exclude particular test spec using `exclude` tag. This prevents use of an `if` condition and additional lines of code. [More details are here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js). Here's how -

```
multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions : {
              args: ['--window-size=900,900']
                    }, 
    },
    {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    // Spec files to be excluded on this capability only.
    exclude: ['spec/doNotRunInChromeSpec.js'], //YOUR SPEC NAME THAT YOU WANT TO EXCLUDE/SKIP
    }],
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much.. Didn't know about exclude tag

Comment: Do you know if the exclude tag is supported in 2.4.0? I upgraded my protractor version now my exclude tag doesn't work at all. I am getting Warning your spec pattern doesn't match with any file message

Comment: @user2744620 it should work. By the looks of your error, it seems that you are providing an incorrect file path or file name. Can you verify it once?  If its still correct, then do open an issue with protractor in github page. Thanks.

Comment: No, In chrome it gets executed. Only in FF it gives me the error. Will double check it

Comment: It is indeed a bug. I lowered the version now and it works. Will create a ticket.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as `browser.getCapabilities()` is asynchronous and is based on [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), your code inside `.then()` may be executed later than the rest of the code. I guess your `if` condition is placed inside `describe` block, which actually runs before the value for `browser.browserName` is set, as a result you get a value of `undefined` for it and condition fails. To make sure that your tests run after all the preparations are done, you should return a promise from `onPrepare`:

```
onPrepare: function() {
    return browser.getCapabilities().then(function (cap) {
        browser.browserName = cap.caps_.browserName;
    });
}
```

Protractor will explicilty wait until it resolves and then start executing the tests.

```
describe('Suite', function () {

    console.log(browser.browserName);  // 'firefox'

    it('spec', function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```